# How can I find out if a process listed in task manager under Windows 8 is running with administrative privileges?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

How can I find out if a process listed in task manager is running with administrative privileges?
I'm running an application using "run as administrator" option, but task manager shows my username in the column "user name".

Comment: That column indicates what user started it.  "Run as administrator" does not actually run the processor as the administrator user only escalate the permission for the process

Comment: So how can I find out if a process has escalated privileges?

Comment: If you used the "run as administrator" then it has admin privileges unless you for an error.  You don't need to confirm the fact it's a given

Comment: I did not  use it. But this is not needed to run application escalated. It can be done using app manifest file and the app will run silently.

Comment: **Your question says otherwise.**  You clearly indicate you are running the application with the "run as administrator".  The task manager does not list or display this information.  If your using a manifest file my conclusion is the same, unless an error is display, the application's permissions were escalated.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I've tried to run via "run as" as well as using manifest file. Both give me the same result. But the question is how to distinct privileged processes in the process list, not how to escalate privileges.

Comment: You can't as a user.  Within the source to the application you can verify the permissions were escalated in many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Taskmgr, go to the details tab, make a right click on the colums and click on "select columns"

[image: select columns]

Now select the entry `Elevated`

[image: Elevated]

Now you have a column Elevated where you can see which programs runs at normal filtered or admin token (elevated).